# C++ Tridimensional Vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that searches for some data and returns a vector:

```
vector<int> findMyData(int byID)
{
  vector<int> tempVect;
  // do some search...
  for ( each data found )
    tempVect.push_back( the data );

  return tempVect;
}
```

Now I have to repeat this search for x rows and y columns, so I'd end up having a bidimensional array of vectors. Am I correct if I say that it could well be a tridimensional vector?

Example:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> myDatabase;
```

The first index should be the row, second index should be the column and the data contained at the x/y point is the vector returned by my function, so the third index is the  number I'll read at the end of the story...

So, how do I fill the database?

```
for (int x=0; x<100; ++x)
  for (int y=0; y<50; ++y)
    myDatabase .... <-- what's the correct syntax to fill this vector?
```

Comment: `n`-dimensional `vector`s are almost always more easily implemented in a single dimension, with you managing the offsets.

Comment: That's right and you also have the opportunity for vast performance benefits: mainly in reduced allocations (given x,y,z it can go from x*y allocations to just 1!!) and in memory locality, though whether the latter is useful depends on your data layout and the consistency of your access patterns.

Comment: It makes sense. But, considering that I don't know the size of the vector that my search function is going to return, how can I instantiate the n-dimensional array beforehand? I would appreciate if you could expand your comment to an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is:

```
myDatabase[x][y]
```

This can also be extended to more dimensions:

```
myDatabase[x][y][z][w][a][b][c]...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> myDatabase(100, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(50));

for (int x=0; x<100; ++x) {
  for (int y=0; y<50; ++y) {
    myDatabase[x][y] = findMyData(getId(x, y));
  }
}
```